# Cakephp complex find condition with count on child table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have two tables topics and posts. Relation: topics hasmany posts. In both table, there is a status field (Y, N) to moderate the content. In my page, I want to list all not moderated topics for which at least one post status is N or topic status itself is N. Is it possible to do with find function in cakephp2.0. Im using Containable behavior.

I need to apply pagination too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one solution:

1. Search on the Post model for **(Posts with N status) OR (Posts which belong to Topics with N status)** and store the **topic_id**
2. Now search on the Topic model for **topics with ID on the list**

Something like this:

```
# TopicsController.php

$ids = $this->Topic->Post->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Post.topic_id')
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            'Post.status' => 'N',
            'Topic.status' => 'N',
        )
    )
));

$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('Topic.id' => (array)$ids),
    'order' => array('Topic.created' => 'DESC')
);

$topics = $this->paginate('Topic');
```

Since you're searching on the Posts model, CakePHP will join the parent Topic data and you can filter by both statuses.

Comment: Thanks.. But I need to apply pagination. So each time I need to get all lists of ids

Comment: @binoy I've updated.. now it paginates the data. You'll need to search for all IDs before paginating since your pagination isn't based on a direct query.. you almost have a sub-query here

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you can use:

```
$conditions => array ('OR' => array ('Topic.status' => 'N', 'Post.status' => 'N'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will explain. I need only to list the topics. For ex:- if topic1 has two posts postA and postB and if postA status is N, I want to list topic1. Also if there is topic2 with no posts and status as N, I want to list that too

Answer (score 1):

Well I haven't tested it but following should work

```
   $this->recursive = -1;        //necessary to use joins

   $options['joins'] = array(
   'table' => 'posts',
   'alias' => 'Post',
   'type' => 'left',
   'conditions' => array('Topic.id = Post.topic_id', 'Post.status = N') //updated code
   );
   $options['group'] = array('Topic.id HAVING count('Topic.id') >= 1 OR Topic.status = N');
   $this->Topic->find('all', $options);
```

Comment: Thanks.. Does not seem to be working this in cakephp2.x. Showing query as SELECT `Topic`.`id`, `Topic`.`user_id`, `Topic`.`title`, `Topic`.`body`, `Topic`.`source`, `Topic`.`status`,  FROM `topics` AS `Topic` posts Post LEFT Array WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY `Topic`.`id` HAVING count(`Post`.`id`) >= 1 OR `Topic`.`status` = 'N'

Comment: I given as 
$this->Topic->find('all', array(
        'joins' => array(
          'table' =>'posts',
          'alias' => 'Post',
          'type' => 'LEFT',
          'conditions' => array('Topic.id  = Post.topic_id AND 
              Post.status = 'N'
              )
        ),
        'group' => array('Topic.id HAVING count(Post.id) >= 1 OR Topic.status = 'N'
      ))));

Comment: Thanks.. We need to give array of array for joins. But I can not give this for pagination. because it is failing for paginate count function since the having clause contains extra column.